How to save an enumeration class in another enumeration class in Java？
I have a table that stores enumeration type values ​​for web select. Here is the table structure:
create table enum_config (
    config_id   bigint auto_increment comment 'id' primary key,
    table_name  varchar(30)  null comment 'table name',
    col_name    varchar(50)  null comment 'column name',
    enum_code   varchar(100) null comment 'enum value',
    enum_name   varchar(500) null comment 'enum name'
) comment 'enums table';




config_id
table_name
col_name
enum_code
enum_name




1
hotel_info
brand_code
1
brand1


2
hotel_info
brand_code
2
brand2


3
hotel_info
hotel_type
1
Self-Operated Hotel


4
hotel_info
hotel_type
2
Franchise Hotel



So I want to create an enumeration class to use as a query parameter.The Java enumeration class I designed is as follows:
@Getter
public enum TableAndColumnEnum {
    HOTEL("hotel_info", xxx);

    private final String tableName;
    private final xxx columnEnum;


    TableAndColumnEnum(String tableName, xxx columnEnum) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.columnEnum = columnEnum;
    }
}

@Getter
public enum TableColumnEnum {
    HOTEL_BRAND_CODE("brand_code"),
    HOTEL_TYPE("hotel_type");
    private final String column;

    TableColumnEnum(String column) {
        this.column = column;
    }
}

I would like to use the field columEnum like this：
String tableName = TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL.tableName;
String columnName = TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL.columnEnum.HOTEL_BRAND_CODE.column;
String columnName = TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL.columnEnum.HOTEL_TYPE.column;

Does Java support this? Thanks!

No, your columnEnum will be a constant of TableColumnEnum. What you're trying to do is similar to TableColumnEnum.HOTEL_TYPE.HOTEL_BRAND_CODE, which is not valid since HOTEL_TYPE does not have a static field named HOTEL_BRAND_CODE.

I don’t understand the point of the second enum type. How is that better than just having two fields, String brand_code; and String hotel_type in the TableAndColumnEnum type?

This doesn't work because what you're asking for is heterogenously typed enum instances which java does not support.
Specifically, you want TableAndColumnEnum, as a type, to simply decree that all instances of this type have a String tableName property, and that all instances have a property named columnEnum.. but that the type of the columnEnum property depends on which instance you're looking at.
And java simply does not work that way. Variation in what members a thing has is solely something you can encode in types, never instances. And enum values are instances.
In other words, TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL can't have different fields (or fields whose type is different) than TableAndColumnEnum.AMUSEMENT_PARK.
You can use abstraction - TableAndColumnEnum as a concept can have a field defined as Column column, and then have subtypes AmusementParkColumn and HotelColumn, each of which extends Column. However, even if at runtime you know guaranteed that TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL.column is of type HotelColumn, the compiler won't let you access things only HotelColumn has without explicitly casting it. So, you wouldn't be able to write TableAndColumnEnum.HOTEL.column.HOTEL_BRAND because HOTEL_BRAND is not a property of the type Column - it's only in HotelColumn.
Matters are even more complicated in the sense that enum instances are kinda sorta subtyped but not in a useful way (so, it seems like this should be possible, but it isn't), and that enums cannot extend each other. So, while you can easily write abstract class Column {}  class HotelColumn extends Column {}, you can't write abstract enum ColumnEnum {} enum HotelEnum extends ColumnEnum {}. So even if you wanted to - you can't; not without leaving enums behind.
The good news is, enums are just syntax sugar with a tiny amount of support in the reflection API. The bad news is, various libraries such as DB abstractions treat enums specially. Still, the basic features of enums (Namely, that they are accessible like field constants, and have the property that any given JVM instance only has exactly 1 instance for each enum value) can be written out by hand.
But java still cannot change its type based solely on an instance, you need to write actual types. Which will end up being a lot of code to maintain:
@RequiredArgsConstructor(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
abstract sealed class TabAndCol permits HotelTabAndCol, AmusementParkTabAndCol {
  public static final HotelTabAndCol HOTEL = HotelTabAndCol.INSTANCE;
  public abstract final AmusementParkTabAndCol AMUSEMENT_PARK = AmusementParkTabAndCol.INSTANCE;

  @Getter private final String tableName;
}

final class HotelTabAndCol extends TabAndCol {
  public static final HotelCol HOTEL_BRAND_CODE = HotelCol.BRAND_CODE;

  private HotelTabAndCol() {
    super("hotel_info");
  }
}

and so on. This 'works' because the types of each 'enum value' (here, public static final fields) is different. You can still have a method that returns all 'enum values' of TabAndCol; it'd return a List<TabAndCol>. But, TabAndCol.HOTEL is an expression of type HotelTabAndCol, and thus, you can invoke e.g. .HOTEL_BRAND on that.
